# Where can I download GenomeDiagram?

Tags: genome

I am trying to install GenomeDiagram but after I accessed to this site

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GenomeDiagram/0.1

I cannot see anything...

Answer (score 0):

The site you are pointing to seems rather outdated.
But they offer an (also outdated) link to the projects home page.
Starting from there you can actually reach a tools [Tools page](https://ics.hutton.ac.uk/software/tools/)
where they state that:

> [..] GenomeDiagram is now part of the larger Biopython project.

Biopython can be found on [biopython.org](http://biopython.org/) and is downloadable on their [downloads page](http://biopython.org/wiki/Download).